# How to save custom input field from checkout page to order in Shopware6 app?

Tags: shopware, shopware6, shopware6-app

I add custom input field to checkout page like this:

```
% sw_extends '@Storefront/storefront/page/checkout/confirm/confirm-shipping.html.twig' %}
{% block page_checkout_confirm_shipping_form %}
{{ parent() }}
<input type="text" id="some_info_text" name="some_info_text">
{% endblock %}
```

I need to save information from this input field to order. This is not plugin, it's an app integration.
It seems app doesn't have event subscribers.
How can I implement this field saving?

I've checked Shopware 6 app docs, but I haven't found right solution.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is no way to do that. From Shopware App you can't influence which data Shopware will send.